# How accurate are Black-Scholes estimates of Vega, Volga, Vanna

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, greeks, estimation, vega

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)) provides analytical formulas for calculating Greeks. I can get Delta, Gamma, Theta all from Bloomberg. I need Vega, Volga, Vanna for my research. Should I use these analytical formulas for now? How accurate are they?

Say the actual Volga of the option is like 1, will they provide an unbiased estimate of Volga like 0.99 or not?

Comment: Hi @Irtza Ahmed. These are analytic formulas. So as long as you implement them right and use the right parameters (forward price and volatility), you'll get the exact Greeks for European vanillas.

Comment: I am not comparing these analytical formulas with monte carlo, or finite difference method. I am comparing the Greeks with the realized ones we experience in the market. Like these greeks depend on the black scholes model assumpetion. BSM does not give correct prices but does it give greeks correct?

Comment: Greeks are associated to a model not to the market. You cannot "experience" "realised" Greeks... This makes no sense. Now maybe your pricing system returns Greeks which you want to compare to these Black-Scholes Greeks? If so clearly even the Deltas will most likely differ, so the second order Greeks will differ even more.

Comment: One can experience greeks. Say the underlying stock moves by 1 cent how much will the call option move. This is approximately delta. Now to estimate this real delta should I use BSM or LV or SV. What do they use when delta hedging

Comment: As you say this is "approximately" delta. It's a market move (hence risk scenario/impact if you like) not a Greek (in the mathematical sense). The difference is that when the stock moves, the impact is not only Delta but also Gamma, Vanna etc. (Taylor expansion)

Comment: You should use the Greeks returned by the pricing model you are using to delta hedge if you want the expected hedging error to be zero in expectation should the market evolves as postulated by your model. You can use any other delta otherwise.

Comment: Ok, so what I understand is that if I use BSM I should use BSM greeks. same for LV and SVol. hmm lets see how it turn out. Btw you know any way to get vanna and volga? under heston

Comment: I think you got it, see also here: See also this: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25244/how-do-different-models-impact-option-greeks and this . 

For Heston, even Vega, i.e. the sensitivity to a single "volatility" number is not straightforward to obtain. It really depends on what you mean by Vega (typically the sensitivity to parallel shift of the whole IV surface). So unfortunately no, there is no straightforward answer to your question.

Comment: so should I just use BSM greeks even when using Heston. Is the vega of BSM comparable to the vega of heston.